# netbeans not stepping through the function being called

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

In my php, I call a function if a certain value is true,

```
if( 1 == 1 ) {
    my_function( variable );
}
```

I can step through the if statement and see what is going on, but for some reason, the step through, goes on the function call line, and it does not step through the actual function code.  It just highlights the function call, then finishes off successfully.

Why is that happening?  I would have thought it would show me the internal workings of the function but steping through the function being called?

Comment: @Dor, that was it.  I didn't know the difference between step over and step into.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Step into" should enter the function.

Answer (score 1):

Add breakpoint in the 1st line of function code you want to step through and try to debug.